# How do I add a serverSide Javascript to a theme?

Tags: xpages

According to the book "Mastering Xpages" the most powerful feature for resources in themes is to use the tag  <resources> and load both clientside and serverSide stuff.

I have tried to load serverSide Javascripts but they do not load.
I can only get clientSide Javascript to load.

My theme:

```
<resources>
        <script
            target="xsp"
            src="/CommonSSJS.jss"
            clientSide="false"
            type="text/javascript"
        ></script>
        <script
            target="xsp"
            src="/xpServerSide.jss"
            clientSide="false"
            type="text/javascript"
        ></script>
        <script
            target="xsp"
            src="/xpCGIVariables.jss"
            clientSide="false"
            type="text/javascript"
        ></script>
        <script
            target="xsp"
            src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"
            clientSide="true"
            type="text/javascript"
        ></script>
        <script
            target="xsp"
            src="include.js"
            clientSide="true"
            type="text/javascript"
        ></script>
    </resources>
```

I know they don't load 'cause I have a call in my framework to a function in one of them.

Please advice!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A theme gets applied during the Render Response phase. So your SSJS libraries are not available in earlier phases. So you can use the SJSS library for e.g. a button but not for logic in e.g. the beforeRenderResponse phase (for this you need to add your SSJS libraries directly to the XPage/custom control).

Comment: Figures… :) In my case I have calls to ssLib in RenderResponse phase in my framework so I just keep the resources within the framwork instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can include SSJS in a theme using this code

```
        <property mode="concat">
        <name>styleClass</name>
        <value>#{javascript:
        var ssjsLibrary:com.ibm.xsp.resource.ScriptResource = new
        com.ibm.xsp.resource.ScriptResource();
        ssjsLibrary.setClientSide(false);
        ssjsLibrary.setSrc("/ssIncludeMe.jss");
        this.addResource(ssjsLibrary); return "";}</value>
    </property>
```

But with the limitations, Per already wrote about.

source: http://www.iqjam.net/iqjam/iqjam.nsf/questionread.xsp?documentId=144ED5F29CB7031F802576E7005732B2&action=openDocument&SessionID=DD0UUYQPUX